# I am trying to increase the border weight of column header of grid in extjs but it doesn't increases more than 1px is there any other way to increase?

Tags: extjs, grid, columnheader

I have used following code for increasing the left border of particular column using id selector:

```
div#PriceCurveCurrent {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution.

```
.x-gridcolumn > .x-header-el {
    border-right-width: 12px;
}
```

Another solution might be to use the ExtJS theme variables.

[Here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#css_var-S-$dataview-item-border-width) is a starting point.